# fopen failed when using wasi-libc

Tags: clang, fopen, libc, wasi, wasmtime

I tried to use `fopen` to read an image when using `wasi-libc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *f = fopen("test.png", "rb");
    printf("file %p\n", f);
    fclose(f);
}
```

Build the code with Clang:

```
$ clang --target=wasm32-wasi --sysroot=/opt/wasi-sdk/share/wasi-sysroot/ test.c -o test.wasm
$ wasmtime test.wasm
$ file 0
```

It returned NULL. How can I sove the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed:

```
wasmtime --dir=. test.wasm
```